# Codeigniter - Where to store Angular 2.0 components?

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

The Angular 2.0 tutorial puts the `index.html` file in the root directory.

e.g.

```
/my-application
     /app
         app.component.ts
         ...
     index.html
```

Codeigniter stores the views in `my-application/views`.

e.g.

```
/my-application
    /views
        index.html
```

Where should I create the `app` directory for Angular 2.0? In `/views`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create an _assets folder in your root and then store the component there

and then open your config.php and define path to your components like as shown below

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/your-site/';
define('CSS', $config['base_url'].'_assets/css/');
define('JS', $config['base_url'].'_assets/js/');
define('IMG', $config['base_url'].'_assets/img/');
```